# Compile c++ source for ARM

Tags: compilation, arm, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I need to compile my source code for ARM. I should do that with cross compiling, or something like that, but I can't figure out how. I use ZMQ and protobuf libs in my project.

For Ubuntu it is compiled with this command:

```
c++ program.cpp protofile.pb.cc -o programexe -lzmq -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf`
```

and everything work fine. So I need to execute this program on my arm board, but first need to compile it for ARM, and this is the step where I stuck. Also, I successfully compiled 'Hello World' with gnueabi and maybe it could help. 
My OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is a way too broad topic to cover in a single question here, especially since you use a lot of libraries that needs to be cross compiled and installed too. Start here rather: http://jensd.be/800/linux/cross-compiling-for-arm-with-ubuntu-16-04-lts (Hopefully your ARM board at least runs linux)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can use the cross-compiler to compile the source code on your Ubuntu and then copy the executable program on your board.

Try to install the compiler with the command `sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`(or aarch32 based on your board's architecture) and then apply the `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` for your source code.